# SQL - Oracle - how to select securities from table with top change %

Tags: sql, oracle, stocks

I need some help to complete a query in SQL-Oracle. I trying to have it select the row(s) or security/ies with the highest or max gain from price1 to price2. here is what i have already. When I try to use sub queries in the select or where clauses, fails....and also i cannot use queries that are hard-quoted because the data in the table will increase periodically to 1000 securites. Any help is appreciated

My query:

```
select security, 
       price1,
       price2,
       ((price2 - price1)/price1)*100 as Percentage
  FROM market
```

My table and data

```
CREATE TABLE market
(security   VARCHAR2(30) PRIMARY KEY,
PRICE1 NUMBER(6, 2),
PRICE2 NUMBER(6, 2));

INSERT INTO market VALUES('A', 62, 178);
INSERT INTO market VALUES('B', 80, 328);
INSERT INTO market VALUES('C', 72, 736);
INSERT INTO market VALUES('D', 270, 565);
INSERT INTO market VALUES('E', 570, 665);
INSERT INTO market VALUES('F', 400, 1640);
INSERT INTO market VALUES('G', 800, 3280);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Although your example doesn't show it, I assume that each single security will have multiple rows with different price1/price2 values, is that correct?

Comment: Do you want the security with the highest percent change (1 row representing your 'answer', or do you want the highest percent change of each security?

Comment: hi brian....for this table there will only be 2 prices. price 1 and price2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this.  Here is one way:

```
select m.*
from (select security, price1, price2, ((price2 - price1)/price1)*100 as Percentage,
             dense_rank() over (order by ((price2 - price1)/price1)*100 desc) as ranking
      from market
     ) m
where ranking = 1;
```

Comment: thanks Gordon. This one worked as well even after i populated the table with new data.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative.

```
select * from
  (select security, price1, price2, ((price2 - price1)/price1)*100 as Percentage
   from market
   order by ((price2 - price1)/price1)*100 desc
  )
where rownum = 1
;
```

Comment: This wont handle ties between securities. Since you have other solutions I'll leave it as is, rather than rewrite it, since I'd likely end up emulating that of Gordon's.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select m.security, x.max_pct_chg
  from market m
  join (select max(((price2 - price1) / price1) * 100) as max_pct_chg
          from market) x
    on ((m.price2 - m.price1) / m.price1) * 100 = x.max_pct_chg
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/182cb0/3/0

Comment: awesome!!!!.... thank you soo... much B. I didn't think it was possible to do it without the 'where' clause. I did populate the table with new data where I now have five securities with the same top percentage increase and all 5 came up in the results.

Comment: @user3650350 no problem, yes, this solution will keep ties